# Shopify CLI can't find hot-reload.js

Tags: localhost, command-line-interface, shopify, hot-reload

I can't see my Shopify theme on the localhost because of this error:

```
**Internal Server Error**

**No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /usr/local/Cellar/shopify-cli/2.10.2/gems/shopify-cli-2.10.2/lib/shopify_cli/theme/dev_server/hot-reload.js**

**WEBrick/1.7.0 (Ruby/3.0.3/2021-11-24) at 127.0.0.1:9292**
```

When I ran theme serve for a second store I have in development without logging out from the first one by mistake, I got an error `127.0.0.1:9292 is already in use` and the message above on the page for http://127.0.0.1:9292/

Since then I logged out, logged in on the right store, ran shopify serve again (same error), uninstalled `shopify-cli`, and installed again but still this message.
I have `shopify-cli-2.11.2` so I don't get why it's looking in a folder 2.10.2 that doesn't exist anymore.

I'm not sure what to do, any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the CLI to see if you received an error referencing the port you're requesting already being in use. If that's the case, there should be a message below suggesting that you change the port using `--port=PORT`.

Should look like:

```
shopify theme serve --port=3030
```